# Subdomain creation in nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, server

I am trying to redirect/rewrite url to create subdomain for subpages. eg: http://example.com/user will return url as http://user.example.com, but not able to figure out any way.
My app is in **ruby on rails** and **nginx** server. Is there any trick to do this?

Comment: How do you want to deal with a request coming to lets say: http://example.com/users/new?

Do you want it to goto: http://new.example.com OR http://users.example.com OR something else?

Comment: i want `example.com/user` to `user.example.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should take care of the subdomain redirection.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location ~ ^/(?<user>[^/]+)/?$ {
        return 301 $scheme://$user.$server_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot. It works great.
One more help, since i am new to **ngnix server** can you suggest me some online resource to understand these **rewrite**, **return** and **regular expression writing** concepts clearly.

Comment: The [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) are a good starting point. I've also found [nginx pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) to be especially helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be best looking at a [wildcard subdomain](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names) on `Nginx`, and accompany that with `Rails` routing for the users.

Remember, Nginx does not have connectivity to your database. So the `Nginx` conf really just needs to be able to send web traffic through the server to your rails app.

The Rails app routing can then be used to send your traffic to specific user pages *if* the user exists. You'd do this with a [`constraint`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints)

--

Here's what I'd do:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (or wherever your nginx config is stored)
server {
    server_name yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com;
    ...
}
```

This will give you the ability to pass any subdomain requests through to your rails app.

I would then do this in your `Rails routes`:

```
config/routes.rb
#put this at the top of the file so it does not conflict
get '', to: 'users#index', constraints: lambda { |request| User.exists?(name: request.subdomain) }
```

Comment: as of now if have this config/routes.rb
`root to: 'pages#home'
 get 'home'          => 'pages#home'`
where pages is my directory stored in **/my_app/app/view/pages** and home is my **home.html.erb** page

Comment: Your question is `I am trying to redirect/rewrite url to create subdomain for subpages.` - I don't understand what `root` has to do with that?

Comment: ok my main line which route me to **home.html.erb** page is `get 'home' => 'pages#home'`

Comment: Sorry this doesn't help. If you want answers, you'll be best explaining your situation properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your Rails app. Simply add a rule to your routes files:

`get '/', to: 'users#show', constraints: { subdomain: /\d+/ }`

Then what ever you visit `*.example.com`, it will redirect to `users#show`.

Check for this tutorial for more information
[Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), Part 3.8.

Otherwise, you can config rewrite in nginx config. I am not sure it works, check [this guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  user.example.com;
  return 301 example.com/user
}
```

Hope it is helpful.

**UPDATE**

You just need to rewrite your nginx config.

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.com;
  rewrite \/home$ $scheme://home.example.com;
}
```

Then save the config, reload nginx using
`sudo service nginx reload` to reload the config file.

Let me know if you still concern.

Comment: actually my routes.rb setting is like this::::::::
root to: 'pages#home'
get 'home'          => 'pages#home'

Comment: i just want to rewrite/return my url as http://example.com/home to http://home.example.com. I am using  Amazon EC2 for hosting.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Cause this route config doesn't relate to your question above.

Comment: When i request for http://example.com/home, that give me a web-page which is in my /my_app/app/view/pages/home.html.erb. Now i just want that my real url appear as http://home.example.com.

Comment: This would be quite constrained as you'd have to set EVERY user in the nginx config

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i just followed ur direction but it is still giving me http://example.com/home.
Acutally as of now i am using **EC2 Public DNS** in place of `example.com`